# How can I call a C# function that takes an Action<T> from F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I need to call this function, from a C# lib:

```
public BinanceRestClient(Action<BinanceRestOptions> optionsDelegate)
  : this((HttpClient) null, (ILoggerFactory) null, optionsDelegate)
{
}
```

How can I call it from F# and pass a `BinanceRestOptions` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass [an anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/lambda-expressions-the-fun-keyword) to it, for example:

```
let bc = BinanceRestClient(fun opts -> ())
```

or

```
let bc = BinanceRestClient(fun opts ->
    opts.SomeProp <- 1
    opts.SomeOtherProp <- "" )
```

Comment: btw, in the first form: let opts = ..., then BinanceRestClient(opts -> ()), the IDE marks opts as unused

Comment: @Thomas  you can use the discard - `fun _ -> ()`.